# Highlight Email And phone Number In RichTextBox WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

Hello I Have A RichTextBox in C# Wpf Application, i want to make A Control To Highlight Email and phone number OnPreviewMouseMove Event How i can Detect the email address and Highlight it ?

Comment: To give directions we need to know where you are now and where you're trying to go. You've told us neither.

Comment: I need to know How i can Detect the email address while the  mouse move on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to highlight emails:

```
string data = richTextBox1.Text;

Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
//find items that matches with our pattern
MatchCollection emailMatches = emailRegex.Matches(data);
foreach (Match item in emailMatches)
{
    var index = item.Index;
    var length = item.Length;

    richTextBox1.Select(index, length);
    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

and you can use same code with different regex for phones depending on the format of phone numbers you desire to detect. I have to clarify that the regex pattern I used may not cover all kinds of emails! So while the code is suitable you need to find a regex pattern for your case.

Comment: Thank You very Much But  please Can You give Me an Example to Detect Phone Number for example In this Format (57444568-4)